# Extruding an object in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opengl object extrusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863790/opengl-object-extrusion)

How can I extrude an object in OpenGL without using a library like http://gts.sourceforge.net/
 ?

Comment: Are you asking how surface extrusion works? Because that's got nothing to do with OpenGL; that's a general graphics question.

Comment: it might not have anything to do with Graphics but i'd like it if there was example code in OpenGL to do it.

Comment: @user1117262 again: OpenGL is for drawing your data. Extrusion is manipulating your data. Sure you could implement some geometry shader that extrudes individual triangles but that's not what extrusion traditionally means. To do it right, you do it on the CPU by manipulating some underlying data structure like [winged-edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_edge) ( [or others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh)) that has better information on neighboring polygons than the vertex list that you use for OpenGL. You then simply use OpenGL to draw the data that you calculated.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i extrude an object in OpenGL without using a library like http://gts.sourceforge.net/

You can't. OpenGL is purely a drawing library, it doesn't process geometry or maintains something you could call a scene.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like [GLE](http://linas.org/gle/).