# How to draw a 3D Hectogon using OpenTK C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, opentk

I have generated a 2D Hectogon in my scene view, however I am now confused as to how to make the shape three dimensional. Any help in the maths or method that is used to calculate this would be greatly appreciated. I have only just started with C# and I feel this is a tall order considering the lack of new relevant content on OpenTk in terms of most of the calls used in most tutorials are now obsolete.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Input;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Graphics;

namespace SimpleGame
{
    class Game : GameWindow
    {

    public Game() : base(1280, 720, new GraphicsMode(32, 24, 0, 4)) // screen resilotion
    {

    }
    int pgmID;
    int vsID;
    int fsID;
    int attribute_vcol;
    int attribute_vpos;
    int uniform_mview;
    int vbo_position;
    int vbo_color;
    int vbo_mview;
    int ibo_elements;
    Vector3[] vertdata;
    Vector3[] coldata;
    Matrix4[] mviewdata;
    int[] indicedata;
    float time = 0.0f;

    void initProgram()
    {

        pgmID = GL.CreateProgram();

        loadShader("F:/Year 1/Semester 2/Simulation In Games/SimpleGame/SimpleGame/vs.glsl", ShaderType.VertexShader, pgmID, out vsID);
        loadShader("F:/Year 1/Semester 2/Simulation In Games/SimpleGame/SimpleGame/fs.glsl", ShaderType.FragmentShader, pgmID, out fsID);


        GL.LinkProgram(pgmID);
        Console.WriteLine(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(pgmID));

        attribute_vpos = GL.GetAttribLocation(pgmID, "vPosition");
        attribute_vcol = GL.GetAttribLocation(pgmID, "vColor");
        uniform_mview = GL.GetUniformLocation(pgmID, "modelview");

        GL.GenBuffers(1, out vbo_position);
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out vbo_color);
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out vbo_mview);

        GL.GenBuffers(1, out ibo_elements);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        initProgram();

        vertdata = new Vector3[] { 

            //new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), // center
            //new Vector3(2.0f, 0f,0f), // right hand side
            //new Vector3(0f,2f,0f), // up

            new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,-0.8f), // center point
            new Vector3(2.0f,0.0f,-0.8f), // right hand side
            new Vector3(1.0f,1.7f,-0.8f), // right hand top 
            new Vector3(-1.0f,1.7f,-0.8f), // right hand top 
            new Vector3(-2.0f,0.0f,-0.8f), // left hand top
            new Vector3(-1.0f,-1.7f,-0.8f),
            new Vector3(1.0f,-1.7f,-0.8f), // right hand top 
        };

        indicedata = new int[]{
            //front
            0, 1, 2,
            0, 2, 3,
            //back
            0, 3, 4,
            0, 4, 5,
            //left
            0, 5, 6,
            0, 6, 1,
        };

        coldata = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3( 0f, 0f, 1f),
            new Vector3( 0f,  1f, 0f),new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3( 0f, 0f, 1f),
            new Vector3( 0f,  1f, 0f),new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3( 0f, 0f, 1f)};

        mviewdata = new Matrix4[]{
            Matrix4.Identity
        };

        Title = "Hello OpenTK!";
        GL.ClearColor(Color.DarkTurquoise);
        GL.PointSize(5f);
    }

    void loadShader(String filename, ShaderType type, int program, out int address)
    {
        address = GL.CreateShader(type);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            GL.ShaderSource(address, sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
        GL.CompileShader(address);
        GL.AttachShader(program, address);
        Console.WriteLine(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(address));
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_vpos);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_vcol);

        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, indicedata.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_vpos);
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_vcol);

        GL.Flush();
        SwapBuffers();
    }

    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo_position);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertdata.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes), vertdata, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(attribute_vpos, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo_color);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(coldata.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes), coldata, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(attribute_vcol, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, true, 0, 0);

        time += (float)e.Time;

        mviewdata[0] = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(0.2f  time)  Matrix4.CreateRotationX(0.0f  time)  Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0.0f, -1.0f, -4.0f) *
        Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.3f, ClientSize.Width / (float)ClientSize.Height, 1.0f, 40.0f); // rotation

        GL.UniformMatrix4(uniform_mview, false, ref mviewdata[0]);

        GL.UseProgram(pgmID);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);


        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ibo_elements);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(indicedata.Length * sizeof(int)), indicedata, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hecto- is 100, Hepta- is 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863790/opengl-object-extrusion

Comment: What do you mean by making a 2d shape three dimensional? You are working with 3d vectors, so your polygon may be flat, but it is three dimensional already. Do you want to convert it into a prism?

Comment: Yes I want to make it into a Prism, I set it out with Vector3's in anticipation of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in method for creating prisms. A prism based on a heptagon (7-sided polygon) is made up from two heptagons (one on the bottom, one on the top) plus 7 vertical 4-sided polygons. So the algorithm for extruding a prism from a horizontal polygon would be (in pseudo code)

```
create_prism(bottom : polygon, height : float) : body
    var top : polygon
    top = bottom.Clone()
    for all vertices v of top
        v.z = v.z + height
    end

    var b = new body
    b.Add(bottom)
    b.Add(top)
    for i : integer = 0 to bottom.Count - 1
        var j : integer
        j = (i + 1) modulo bottom.Count
        var side = new polygon[4]
        side[0] = bottom[i]
        side[1] = bottom[j]
        side[2] = top[j]
        side[3] = top[i]
        b.Add(side)
    end
    return b
end
```